# Parse Datetime in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

[image]

I have the checkout column in Dataframe of type 'object' in '2017-08-04T23:31:19.000+02:00' format.
But i want it in the format as shown in the image.
Can anyone help me please.

Thank you:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to convert the object column to a date time column, then use the built in `date` and `time` functions.

```
# create an intermediate column that we won't store on the DataFrame
checkout_as_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout'])

# Add the desired columns to the dataframe
df['checkout_date'] = checkout_as_datetime.dt.date
df['checkout_time'] = checkout_as_datetime.dt.time
```

Though, if you're goal isn't to write these specific new columns out somewhere, but to use them for other calculations, it may be simpler to just overwrite your original column and use the datetime methods from there.

```
df['checkout'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout'])
df['checkout'].dt.date  # to access the date
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but something along the lines of:

```
 df['CheckOut_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["CheckOut_date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
 df['CheckOut_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["CheckOut_time"].dt.strftime('%H:%m:%s'))
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the day in the `strftime` call for `CheckOut_date`.